# React Fetch Returning Wrong Route from Express Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on setting up a React frontend that queries data from an Express backend. I have 2 routes set up: `users` and `stories`. The `users` route is working correctly. However when I try to fetch the `stories` route, it's still returning the `users` data, and I'm not sure why.

I'm hoping someone can help point out why no matter what path I set the `fetch` to in `ComponenetDidMount`, I always get the `users` data returned.

My React component looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    stories: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/stories')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(stories => this.setState({ stories }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
```

Below is the GET route for users, and stories

#### Users

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([{
    id: 1,
    username: "Kobe",
    email: 'kobe@kobe.com',
    password: 'kobe'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    username: "Bob",
    email: 'bob@bob.com',
    password: 'bob'
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### Stories

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([{
    id: 1,
    author_id: 1,
    title: "A Dog's Blog",
    body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    author_id: 2,
    title: "Bob's Blog",
    body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### App.js (Express)

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/scripts')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/stories', usersRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And my `bin/www` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('express-template:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm sure the answer is staring me right in the face.

Comment: Sorted it out. Was missing the `storiesRouter` version of `var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');` in `App.js` (Express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it out. Was missing the storiesRouter version of `var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');` in App.js (Express)